# Laravel modal form pass input to controller as parameter

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, forms

I have a button that calls a modal form where user can change their group name. I want to pass the id into the form `{!! Form::open(['action' => [ 'ContactsController@update', id]]) !!}`. I tried using the same way that I passed value to group name input using jquery but can't work.

**Button code:**

```
 {{ Form::button('<i class="material-icons">dvr</i>', ['type' => 'button', 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-link btn-just-icon edit_btn', 'data-toggle'=>'modal', 'data-name'=>"$group_contact->group_name" 'data-id'=>"$group_contact->id", 'data-target'=>'#editGroupModal'] )  }}
```

**Modal form code:**

```
  {!! Form::open(['action' => [ 'ContactsController@update', ???],'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
      <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
          <input type="hidden" name="eventId" id="eventId"/>
          <span id="idHolder"></span>   
        {{Form::label('group_name','',['class' => 'bmd-label-floating', 'placeholder' => 'Enter group name'])}}
        {{Form::text('group_name','',['class' => 'form-control', 'autocomplete'=>'off'])}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        {{Form::submit('Update', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
      </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Update Controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the way to do it by changing the attribute of action

```
$('#contactsEditForm').attr('action', '/contacts/' + groupID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a route for each controller function.

```
e.g Route::POST('/update-group', 'ContactsController@update')->name('update.group');

public function update(Request $request) {
 try {
     $input = $request->all(); 
     //$input['input_field_name']
  } catch (\Throwable $th) {
      echo "<pre>";print_r($th->__toString());die;
   }
}
```

And you have already passed `Id` in the hidden field.

Type this in your form `action` `{!! Form::open(['route' => 'update.group','method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}`.

Or you can pass a parameter in the URL like below.

```
Route::POST('/update-group/{id}', 'ContactsController@update');
{!! Form::open(['action' => route('update-group', ['id' => $id])])!!}
```

Hope this will help! :) :) :) :)

Comment: So there isn't other way than created each function controller?

Comment: Can you please post the error message here for better clarification.

Comment: or i thinking of changing the attribute $('#contactsEditForm').attr('action',  data[0]);